# Как правильно использовать doGet и doPost?

Tags: java, servlet

У меня простое `web` приложение на `tomcat` с несколькими функциями. Есть меню навигации и я пытаюсь реализовать одну из функций(удаление), она должна получив данные с одной `jsp` страницы просто напечатать их на другую (базу потом прикручу и будет удалять). То есть с `delete.jsp` после заполнения формы с `id` для удаления меня должно перенаправлять на `answer.jsp` где будет напечатан этот `id`.

У меня проблемы с пониманием как многократно использовать методы `doGet` и `doPost` при этом учитывая что страниц может быть и много.

Есть главная страница с ней все хорошо хотя-бы в том смысле что навигация работает:

```
index.jsp
<body>

    <ul>

        <li><a href="find.jsp">Найти пользователя по id</a></li>
        <li><a href="addition.jsp">Добавить пользователя</a></li>
        <li><a href="edition.jsp">Редактировать пользователя</a></li>
        <li><a href="delete.jsp">Удалить пользователя</a></li>

    </ul>

</body>
```

Это `delete.jsp` он принимает данные.

```
<body>

    <form action="answer.jsp" method="post">
        <input type="number" placeholder="id" name="id"><br>
        <input type="submit" value="ответить">
    </form>

</body>
```

Это `answer.jsp` он должен напечатать данные:

```
<body>
    ${serverAnswer}
</body>
```

И сервлет который должен это выполнять, тут все мои муки:

```
@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {

    req.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

    req.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp").forward(req, resp);

}


@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {

    req.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

    //тут я хочу вытащить из запроса id и послать его в ответ.
    final String id = req.getParameter("serverAnswer");


    req.setAttribute("id", id);

    doGet(req, resp);
}
```

И что-то я запутался.

Как мне контролировать с каким из `jsp` файлов я работаю в методах, особенно если один метод работает с разными файлами? И почему в `doPost` выражение `id = req.getParameter("serverAnswer")` не дает мне результата? Вероятно я не указал от какого файла он должен его получить, но если я это укажу, то как мне потом с этим методом работать с другими файлами...

Как мне сделать что-бы это заработало. Только-только начал разбираться с сервлетами, пожалуйста не кидайте тухлыми яйцами.

Comment: Лучше уж фреймворк учить, чем уставшие сервлеты

Comment: Параметр нужно в response устанавливать

Comment: Ты работаешь только с одним JSP который возврашаешь. JSP просто отправляют запросы который сервлет обрабатывает и вызывает твой метод с объектом request. Зачем ты doGet вызываешь который index.jsp возвращает?

Comment: Устанавливать кодировку запроса в сервлете не надо

Comment: @Alex78191 по поводу фреймворка я тут пока не властен делаю задание которое ментор дал, хотя любой фреймворк все равно использует внутри сервлеты, не плохо бы наверно разузнать как оно внутри работает. >>Параметр нужно в response устанавливать<< может быть имелся в виду setAttribute?

Comment: Я это и имел в виду

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`doGet()` и `doPost()` - это низкоуровневые методы, которые просто принимают любой запрос определенного типа (и, на самом деле, не очень нужны при наличии `service()`. Предполагается, что между этими методами и реальным обработчиком запроса должен существовать некоторый дополнительный компонент, который находит этот обработчик и передает ему запрос. Если бы вы использовали какой-то фреймворк, то там то уже было бы сделано за вас, в данном случае необходимо реализовать этот сервис руками. В результате у вас получится следующая схема:

- Клиент посылает GET запрос /find.jsp
- Сервер перенаправляет его в .doGet() сервлета
- В методе .doGet() (или в .service()) ваш сервис раскладывает url на составляющие и сопоставляет find.jsp с необходимым обработчиком, после чего передает запрос ему

Еще раз подчеркну, что `.doXXX()` - это такие сервлетные черные дыры, куда поступают все запросы соответствующего HTTP-метода - вне зависимости от того, какая страница была запрошена. Таким образом туда может попасть и `find.jsp`, и `answer.jsp` - задача выяснения того, как сопоставляются пути с обработчиками запроса лежит на реализующем сервлет (т.е. на вас).

Comment: service() просто служит диспетчером для doXXX методов.

Comment: @etki а каким образом внутри метода doPost() я могу узнать к какому из jsp в данном случае пришел запрос, чтобы задать ему корректные атрибуты?

Comment: @Alex78191 поэтому я и написал, что они не нужны

Comment: @Павел в переданном HttpServletRequest есть несколько методов (getRequestURI(), getPathInfo()), которые позволяют получить запрошенный путь

Comment: @Павел Связывать сервлеты  с URL можно через web.xml или с помощью `@WebServlet`. http://devcolibri.com/4284

Comment: @etki Они как раз нужны потому что в одном методы запросы всех HTTP методов обрабатывать тупо.

Comment: @Alex78191 тупо группировать запросы по методу, но ничего не делать с путем. В большинстве случаев с REST запросы в первую очередь группируются по ресурсу, и потом уже - по методу. Здесь хоть как ни посмотри, роутинг всегда будет основываться на паре метод-путь, поэтому любая группировка (по методу или по пути) практически всегда бессмысленна.

Comment: @etki чтобы сгруппировать по ресурсу и нужно связать сервлет с URL.

Comment: @Alex78191 такое ощущение, что вы повторяете то, что я написал

Comment: @etki вы написали, что группировка бессмысленна